# Using multiple manifest files to load to Redshift from S3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have a large manifest file containing about 460,000 entries (all S3 files) that I wish to load to Redshift. Due to issues beyond my control a few (maybe a dozen or more) of these entries contain bad JSON that will cause a COPY command to fail if I pass in the entire manifest at once. Using COPY with a key prefix will also fail in the same way.

To get around this I have written a Python script that will go through the manifest file one URL at a time and issue a COPY command for each one using psycopg2. The script will additionally catch and log any errors to ensure that the script runs even when it comes across a bad file, and allows us to locate and fix the bad files.

The script has been running for a little more than a week now on a spare EC2 instance and is only around 75% complete. I'd like to lower the run time, because this script will be used again.

My understanding of Redshift is that COPY commands are executed in parallel, and with that I had an idea - will splitting the manifest file into smaller chunks and then running the script each of those chunks reduce the time it takes to load all the files?

Answer (score 1):

COPY command can load multiple files in parallel very fast and efficiently. So when you run one COPY command for each file in your python file, that's going to take a lot of time since you are not taking advantage of parallel loading.

So maybe you can write a script to find bad JSONs in your manifest and kick them out and run a single COPY with the new clean manifest?

Or like you suggested, I would recommend splitting manifest file into small chunks so that COPY can run for multiple files at a time. (NOT a single COPY command for each file)